# How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I've written a couple of functions that effectively replicate JSON.stringify(), converting a range of values into stringified versions. When I port my code over to JSBin and run it on some sample values, it functions just fine. But I'm getting this error in a spec runner designed to test this.

My code:

```
  // five lines of comments
  var stringify = function(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'function') { return undefined;}  // return undefined for function
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') { return undefined;} // return undefined for undefined
  if (typeof obj === 'number') { return obj;} // number unchanged
  if (obj === 'null') { return null;} // null unchanged
  if (typeof obj === 'boolean') { return obj;} // boolean unchanged
  if (typeof obj === 'string') { return '\"' + obj + '\"';} // string gets escaped end-quotes
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) { 
    return obj.map(function (e) {  // uses map() to create new array with stringified elements
        return stringify(e);
    });
  } else {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);   // convert object's keys into an array
    var container = keys.map(function (k) {  // uses map() to create an array of key:(stringified)value pairs
        return k + ': ' + stringify(obj[k]);
    });
    return '{' + container.join(', ') + '}'; // returns assembled object with curly brackets
  }
};

var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {
    if (typeof stringify(obj) != 'undefined') {
        return "" + stringify(obj) + "";
    }
};
```

The error message I'm getting from the tester is:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at stringify (stringifyJSON.js:18:22)
    at stringifyJSON (stringifyJSON.js:27:13)
    at stringifyJSONSpec.js:7:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Context.<anonymous> (stringifyJSONSpec.js:5:26)
    at Test.Runnable.run (mocha.js:4039:32)
    at Runner.runTest (mocha.js:4404:10)
    at mocha.js:4450:12
    at next (mocha.js:4330:14)
```

It seems to fail with:
stringifyJSON(null) for example

Comment: please provide the input for which you are getting error, as its working for stringifyJSON({a:'b',c:'d'})

Comment: Aside from the error, `stringifyJSON([1,2,3])` returns `1,2,3` and  `stringifyJSON({foo: 'bar'})` returns `{foo: "bar"}`, both of which are not valid JSON.

Comment: My guess would be this line `if (obj === 'null') { return null;} // null unchanged`, - that won't pass when given `null`, only if given the string `"null"`. So if you pass the actual `null` value to your script, it will be parsed in the Object part of the code. And `Object.keys(null)` throws the `TypeError` mentioned. To fix it, use `if(obj === null) {return null}` - without the qoutes around `null`.

Comment: Another issue: your code does not handle the possibility of embedded `"` characters in strings.

Comment: @Pointy - yes, i'll need to add some logic for that...thank you

Comment: @zahabba : no problem. I reposted that as the answer, so your question won't linger in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

**Generic answer**

This error is caused when you call a function that expects an *Object* as its argument, but pass *undefined* or *null* instead, like for example

```
Object.keys(null)
Object.assign(window.UndefinedVariable, {})
```

As that is usually by mistake, the solution is to check your code and fix the *null/undefined* condition so that the function either gets a proper *Object*, or does not get called at all.

```
Object.keys({'key': 'value'})
if (window.UndefinedVariable) {
    Object.assign(window.UndefinedVariable, {})
}
```

**Answer specific to the code in question**

The line `if (obj === 'null') { return null;} // null unchanged`  will not 
evaluate when given `null`, only if given the string `"null"`. So if you pass the actual `null` value to your script, it will be parsed in the Object part of the code. And `Object.keys(null)` throws the `TypeError` mentioned. To fix it, use `if(obj === null) {return null}` - without the qoutes around null.

Comment: Highlight: *"And `Object.keys(null)` throws the `TypeError` mentioned."*

Comment: To add another common example where this happens: `delete obj.property` where `obj===null`

Answer (score 35):

Make sure that object is not empty (null or undefined ).

**Error:**

```
let obj

Object.keys(obj)
```

**Solution:**

```
Object.keys(obj || {})
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution, it worked for me : Object.keys(obj || {})

Comment: This is the best solution, this happens mostly if you are programmatically deciding the value of the object `obj` and by chance your logic for determining its value returns a falsy value (null or undefined) so telling it to use a truthy value or an object with no property is the best answer.

Comment:  Smiling Face with Open Hands `|| {}`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that destination object is not empty ( `null` or `undefined` ).

You can initialize destination object with empty object like below:

```
var destinationObj = {};

Object.assign(destinationObj, sourceObj);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very useful to avoid errors when accessing properties of null or undefined objects.

null to undefined object

```
const obj = null;
const newObj = obj || undefined;
// newObj = undefined
```

undefined to empty object

```
const obj; 
const newObj = obj || {};
// newObj = {}     
// newObj.prop = undefined, but no error here
```

null to empty object

```
const obj = null;
const newObj = obj || {};
// newObj = {}  
// newObj.prop = undefined, but no error here
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding `Object &&` works before putting the object on to map.

```js
objexts && Object.keys(objexts)?.map((objext, idx) =>
```

Comment: this one work like magic on me... thanks !

Comment: This works but is not technically the most efficient solution. Karthikeyan.a solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to always call Object properties on an object:

```
Object.keys(obj || {}) //so you avoid calling it on null/undefined
```

It resolved my error!

Comment: Repeats [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72882442/861716).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added Lucid extension to Chrome and didn't notice the problem at that moment. After about a day of working on the problem and turning the program upside down, in a post someone had mentioned Lucid. I remembered what I had done and removed the extension from Chrome and ran the program again. The problem was gone. I am working with React. I thought this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem in a React Native project. I solved it using this.

```js
let data = snapshot.val();
if(data){
  let items = Object.values(data);
}
else{
  //return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (typeof obj === 'undefined') { return undefined;} // return undefined for undefined
if (obj === 'null') { return null;} // null unchanged
```

with

```
if (obj === undefined) { return undefined;} // return undefined for undefined 
if (obj === null) { return null;} // null unchanged
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Laravel**, my problem was in the name of my Route.
Instead:

```
Route::put('/reason/update', 'REASONController@update');
```

I wrote:

```
Route::put('/reason/update', 'RESONController@update');
```

and when I fixed the controller name, the code worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an extra pair of parenthesis `()`

Instead of

```
export default connect(
  someVariable
)(otherVariable)()
```

It had to be

```
export default connect(
  someVariable
)(otherVariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet is sufficient to understand how I encountered the same issue but in a different scenario and how I solved it using the guidance in the accepted answer. In my case I was trying to log the keys of object present in the 0th index of the 'defaultViewData' array using Object.keys() method.

```
defaultViewData = [{"name": "DEFAULT_VIEW_PLP","value": {"MSH25": "LIST"}}] 

console.log('DEFAULT_VIEW', Object.keys(this.props.defaultViewData[0]));
```

The console.log was not getting printed and I was getting the same error as posted in this question. To prevent that error I added below condition

```
    if(this.props.defaultViewData[0]) {
  console.log('DEFAULT_VIEW', Object.keys(this.props.defaultViewData[0]));
}
```

Adding this check ensured that I didn't get this error. I hope this helps for someone.

Note: This is React.js code. (although to understand the problem it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

```
reactTraverser.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys (<anonymous>) at reactTraverser.js:6
```

If you are getting this error on typeScript Try using it without Live Server this error will not be displayed

Answer (score 0):

My API requests got expired so it was passing a null value that was giving this error.

Might as well check your API limits.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgu2C.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(obj ?? {})`

It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with a element in a webform. So what I did to fix it was validate.
if(Object === 'null')
     do something