# How to resolve this " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object "

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

My function is :

```
function collect_que_ids(e) {
  var val = e.val();
  var data_lo = e.attr('data-lo');
  new_hash = {};
  new_hash[val] = data_lo;
  if(e.is(':checked')){
    if(checked_box_hash.includes(new_hash)){
      checked_box_hash;
    }else{
      checked_box_hash.push(new_hash);
    }
  }
  else{
    new_hash_key = Object.keys(new_hash)[0]
    new_hash_value = new_hash[new_hash_key]
    $.each(checked_box_hash, function(key, value){
      if (typeof Object.keys(value) !== 'nil') {
        current_key = Object.keys(value)
        if (current_key[0] == new_hash_key && value[current_key[0]] == new_hash_value) {
          checked_box_hash.splice(key, 1)
        }
      }
    })
  }
};
```

I am getting error on this line.

```
if (typeof Object.keys(value) !== 'nil') {
```

Need to resolve it. please help to do.

Comment: make a console.log(Object.keys(value)) and see what is the value of it

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is no "nil" type in JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe `typeof value !== 'undefined' && value && Object.keys(value).length`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Object.keys(value)` returns an *array* and to check if it is undefined or empty do this

```
 if (typeof Object.keys(value) !== 'undefined' && Object.keys(value).length > 0) {
        // You have an array 
    }
```

Comment: For any future readers: This answer is incorrect. The error is created when `value` is null or undefined. The above check will not prevent it from throwing an error. `Object.keys()` will always return an array and will never return undefined. Use `Object.keys(value || {}).length > 0` or `Object.keys(value ?? {}).length > 0`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using React classes that extend `PureComponent`, then make sure you put your state in the class field, `state = {...}`, not the State type definition, `type State = {...}`, or else it will be an error because it actually was null.