# The "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" when using filter method" in Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The code looks as following:

```
getSections () {
  if (!this.document) {
    return []
  }

  return Object.keys(this.document.Sections).filter(x => this.document.Sections[x])
}
```

The this.document.Sections is object that contains properties (objects as well).

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: can you please confirm if this.document.Sections is a non-empty object, try consoling it.

Comment: I've updated the original post. Please, take a look above.

Comment: The code does in no way guarantee, that `this.document.Sections` is not `undefined` (or `null`, though unlikely), even after the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message says, this error comes from passing null to Object.keys. Try it in the console:

```
Object.keys(null)

VM198:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
```

So, in your code `this.document.Sections` is `null`.

Here you have an option to fix it. Hope it helps.

```
function getSections() {
    return (this.document && this.document.Sections)
        ? Object.keys(this.document.Sections)
            .filter(x => this.document.Sections[x])
        : [];
}
```

See it in a snippet:

```js
var test = {
    document: {
        Sections: {
            a: 1,
            b: undefined,
            c: 3
        }
    }
};

function getSections() {
    return (test.document && test.document.Sections)
        ? Object.keys(test.document.Sections)
            .filter(x => test.document.Sections[x])
        : [];
}
console.log(getSections())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `this.document.Sections` is null or undefined

```js
getSections () {
  if (!this.document && !this.document.Sections) {
    return []
  }

  return Object.keys(this.document.Sections).filter(x => this.document.Sections[x])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[1,null,2,undefined,{},3].filter(x => isFinite(x) && x > 1)` produces `[2, 3]`

`[1,null,2,undefined,{},3].filter(x => x !== null && x != undefined)` produces`[1, 2, {}, 3]`

Just specify the correct criteria in the filter.

Answer (score -1):

That error could be more helpfully written as: "one of your variables was null or undefined"

There aren't many to choose from, but you will need to do a little local debugging to work out which, and why.

Comment: I've updated the original post. Please, take a look above.

Comment: Still, it could be that  this.document.Sections  is null, or that  x is null/undefined