# Iterating through JSON Objects in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm currently struggling to iterate through a JSON Object I'm fetching from a third-party API. Haven't really dealt with fetching APIs before as you will probably see.

---

Here is the JSON file I am fetching:
[Link to the JSON file](https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.3.1/data/en_US/champion.json)

---

To fetch the data I'm using a useFetch script which looks like this:

```js
// useFetch.js

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

function useFetch(url) {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    async function fetchUrl() {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json = await res.json();
        setData(json);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUrl();
    }, []);

    return [data, loading];
}

export { useFetch };
```

---

What I'm trying to export later on is simply the name of each character / champion (who is an object by itself including name, description etc.)

---

```js
// App.js

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFetch } from "../components/useFetch";

const App = () => {
    const [data, loading] = useFetch(
        "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.3.1/data/en_US/champion.json"
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data)
    })

    return (
        <div>
           <ul>
              {Object.keys(data.data).map((item, i) => (
                  <li key={i}> // every character has got an ID as well I'd like to pass here later. The output is just a dummy rn.
                      <p>{data.data}</p>
                  </li>
              ))}
           </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Unfortunately I'm running into an error while trying to convert the JSON object `data.data` which says:

`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`
which points to my iteration in the JSX.

What I've tried was targeting those empty rules and give them a string as a result like

```js
if ((typeof Object === null) || (typeof Object === undefined)) { 
  return '-' 
}
```

or

```js
if ((item === null) || (item === undefined)) { 
  return '-' 
}
```

[as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205)

but it obviously didn't help.

I'd be thankful for any tips / optimizations with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Comment: I've already taken a look at this but I didn't seem to implement its possible fix correctly.

Comment: Is `data.data` undefined or null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too in to react hooks but you set data  to `[]` so  `data.data` will be undefined until the data is actually fetched.

Will it work if you set `const [data, setData] = useState({ data: [] });` in useFetch?

Comment: This actually fixed it I guess. I've tried to set it to `useState({});` before and forgot the data property and ran into the same error. Thanks a lot.