# How to add a new column to the table, based on checkbox selection in angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have a table containing some rows.The table data comes from loop.Here I need to add new columns based on selection of checkbox.Suppose I checked product,a new table heading will create as product along with blank rows just below the table heading,again If I uncheck created columns will be removed.New columns should create before add button.Here is the code below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-focus

### app.component.html

```
    <div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p> 
<div><button (click)="enable()">Edit</button> <input type="checkbox" value="product">Product&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="market">market</div>  
  <table class="table border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Business</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
       <td> <input #focus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.name}}"> </td>
       <td> <input [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.items}}"> </td>
       <td> <button (click)="addRow(i)">Add</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
selectedRow : Number;

@ViewChild('focus') input: ElementRef;
      public toggleButton: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  groups=[
     {
       "name": "pencils",
       "items": "red pencil"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers",
       "items": "big rubber"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers1",
       "items": "big rubber1"
     },
  ];
  addRow(index): void {
    var currentElement = this.groups[index];
    this.groups.splice(index, 0, currentElement);
 }
 enable(){
    this.toggleButton = false
    setTimeout(()=>{ // this will make the execution after the above boolean has changed
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    this.selectedRow = 0;
  },0); 
    }
  setClickedRow(index) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make a ng-for on the `<th>` based on your groups properties. Add properties on groups when the user hits the checkbox.

Comment: I tried but I was not able to push a new column properly

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Right now you have `Items` and `Business` as columns. So, do you want to add `Product` and `Market` when checked? When added, what would be the table row values for those columns?

Comment: It should be empty

Comment: Yes, it should be empty

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57790891/2924577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my StackBlitz for live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-focus-77xrnn

To add or remove `columns` dynamically, we have to first fetch the values from the component instead of hard coding them in the template.

```
columns = ["Items", "Business"];
```

**Component:**

And whenever a column checkbox is toggled, we listen to the `change` event and add or delete the column accordingly.

```
onColumnStatusChange(column, isChecked) {
  if (isChecked) {
    // Add column to the table.

    this.columns.push(column);

    this.groups.forEach(value => {
      value[column] = "";
    });
  } else {
    // Delete column from the table.

    this.columns.splice(this.columns.indexOf(column), 1);

    this.groups.forEach(value => {
      delete value[column];
    });
  }
}
```

**Template:**

In the template, columns and also table row items must be fetched dynamically.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="product" (change)="onColumnStatusChange($event.target.value, $event.target.checked)">Product&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" value="market" (change)="onColumnStatusChange($event.target.value, $event.target.checked)">market
  ...
  ...
<tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
     <th>{{ column }}</th>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
  ...
  ...
<tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(row); let j = index">
      <td><input #focus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row[item]}}"></td>
   </ng-container> 
   <td><button (click)="addRow(i)">Add</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have added this code in my project but not able to fetch the table data onload its showing error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"... is there any solution for it?

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - I'm not sure what is the causing that error. Make sure your `groups` and `columns` values are not `null` or `undefined`. Also, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29721434/2924577). If still not resolved, reproduce same error in a StackBlitz and I'll take a look.

Comment: I am getting column/thead value but problem with tbody  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of objectKeys(row); let j = index">
          <td> <input #focus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row[item]}}"> </td>  , I am not getting here how you are getting items and business data?

Comment: As shown in the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-focus-77xrnn), make sure you add `objectKeys = Object.keys;` in your component. This second `*ngFor` is nested in first `*ngFor` and is getting `row` value from that first `*ngFor`.