# Accessing the Object received from Django Rest API and passed to props creates a TypeError in the render() method of React

Tags: javascript, django-rest-framework, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

Description: After registering with token authentication at the DRF I receive the token and a json user object into my authReducer, which is passed further down into my rootReducer, and stored as `auth.user`in my state.
The `user` object is:

`{id:1, first:"first", last:"last", username:"Santa",email:"xyz@gmail.com"}`,
and can be called with

```
render(){
console.log(this.props.user);
return(){...
```

inside the render function of a React class based component.

The state is mapped to the props:

```
        mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
        return{
        user:state.auth.user,
        }
    }
export default connect(mapStateToProps,)(ProfileUpdate)
```

Everything works - the object appears inside the console like above, however if I try to access the values of the object like:

```
render(){
const user=this.props.user;
console.log(user.first);
return(){...
```

I receive a `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object.`

But doing:

```
render(){
const user=this.props.user;
user=new Object(user);
console.log(user.first);
return(){...
```

works.
Why is that?
Do I always have to create a new Object?

Comment: the second block you claim to be working contains a TypeError (you are assigning to a const)

Comment: `console.log(this.props.user)` works - logs the entire object, `user=this.props.user; console.log(user.first)` does not work, but `user=this.props.user; user=new Object(user); console.log(user.first)` works again.

Comment: the error is not reproducible based on the code you've provided

Comment: try looking at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Comment: @ErnstPlesiutschnig before using user data check for undefined or null then proceed.

Comment: @UmeshMGowda: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`, if I do an `if(user.first!=null || user.first!=undefined){...}`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski: The object is there (in the state), but I cannot destructure the values without an `user=new Object(this.props.user)`call.

Comment: @UmeshMGowda: Correction: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of null` is the proper mistake.

Comment: check `user` for being null not `user.first`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski: I tried that but cannot run checks, e.g. `user.hasOwnProperty()`. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null`.

If I do: `console.log(typeof(this.props.user)` -> `object`.

If I do a `const=mapStateToProps=(state)=>{return{user: new Object(state.auth.user)` }} I can destructure it.

Comment: authReducer: `const initialState={ token: localStorage.getItem('token'), user:null}` `const authReducer=(state=initialState, action)=>{...`This gets combined inside the `rootReducer=combineReducers({ auth:authReducer,...}`

Comment: `typeof null === object` my man, one of the nuances of javascript