# Angular build prod fail at runtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an error on an angular project. When I try to do a **ng build --prod**, sometimes it results in a faulty build which won't load when deployed.

I found this error :

```
main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
at n.value (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at n.value (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at n.value (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at new e (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at Object.o [as factory] (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at e.value (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at e.value (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at Oe (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
at Se (main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1)
(anonymous) @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
_ @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
Promise.then (async)
m @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
P @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
value @ polyfills.905beb69df21b0ed5a3e.js:1
e.setDriver @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
e @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
e.exports.4.3 @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
r @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
e @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
oAJy @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
a @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
VUM0 @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
a @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
G13Q @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
a @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
zUnb @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
a @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
0 @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
a @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
t @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
r @ runtime.3e6148e4e88307435198.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.eae7de579345243bc665.js:1
```

After a long investigation, there were no issue with the lasts commits (the build failing at some previously working commits)

Did anyone face a similar issue? It might be linked to zone.js but couldn't find how to fix the issue :/

EDIT : Not a solution bug removing "optimization": true seems to fix the issue

Thank you in advance,
Cordially,
Matthieu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Comment: Hello, 
It could but we can't pinpoint the origin of the error in our code so we can't fix it this way. Also old commits that used to build without this issue do have the error sometimes now :/