# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object in vue js axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an error that says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

iIt's my first time in javascript. what's problem with this code?

```
<template>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-5">
                <div class="card rounded shadow">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <p>Login YukPilih App</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form @submit.prevent="userLogin()">
                          <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" v-model="username">
                          </div>
                          <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" v-model="password">
                          </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                username: null,
                password: null
            }
        },

        methods: {
            userLogin: function(){
                axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login',{
                    username: this.username,
                    password: this.password
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Look at error message if there is line number, like `app.js:41` (41 is line number)

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. The error appears in specific situations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object when null or undefined value is provided where an object is expected, the code doesn't seem to contain anything that could cause it. As said, it's possible to track the problem on your side based on error stack.