# Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.entries (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to pull data from the console on one page, written in json and then transfer it to another using this script, but I'm having problems.
Help solve the problem)

JS code

```
chosen = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chosen'))
console.log(chosen)
let s = "";
let sum = 0.0;

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(chosen)) {
    s += `<p>${key} (${value['value']}): \u20ac ${value['price']}</p>`
    sum += parseFloat(value['price'])
}
s += `<p>Total: ${sum}</p>`

document.getElementById("components").innerHTML += s;
```

Error

```
order.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at order.js:6
```

Comment: What does `console.log(chosen)` output?

Comment: The error makes it sound like **chosen** does not have a value. Either the *sessionStorage* value is empty for it, or it is not properly parsed (possibly due to the format being wrong/off).

Comment: @ADyson the selected product and its cost. 
{Video card: {…}, Processor: {…}, Motherboard: {…}, Memory: {…}, SSD: {…}, …}

Comment: that's what the console puts out yet that error would be created? u sure?

Comment: the console log is saved in this format
`chosen[key] = {value, price}
    console.log(chosen)
    sessionStorage.setItem('chosen', JSON.stringify(chosen)); `

Comment: As I see you didn't define chosen correctly. What can of variable is that? const or let? Start by fixing this. Or, did you forget to add it here in the question?

Comment: Assuming `chosen` is defined earlier, then the code does produce an error, but not the one you're claiming - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h9z3p87k/ . And, are you sure you're retrieving data from the same session where it's already stored? It would be wise to write a line which checks if the storage value exists before trying to parse it.

Comment: Even if we fix all the syntax issues, it still doesn't make much sense. I'm guessing this is more like what you were aiming for: https://jsfiddle.net/h9z3p87k/1/ . Does that output what you expected? The example data you've given doesn't seem to really match up with the code very well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you define your chosen variable correctly and try again?

This `chosen = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chosen'))` should be like this => `const chosen = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('chosen'))`