# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting an error when trying to delete object. Currently there is no data as it is added through out other code. May issue is that I may need to delete the data if it exist. I guest I need a way to check if the data exist before deleting

Error message: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

The error is coming from this line: delete rooms?.[roomId]?.[socket.id];

```
interface IDevice {
    deviceId: string;
    deviceName?: string;
    socketId: string;
    isReconnecting?: true | false;
}

const rooms: Record<string, Record<string, IDevice>> = {};

if (typeof rooms?.[roomId]?.[socket.id] !== 'undefined' && rooms?.[roomId]?.[socket.id] !== null) {
     delete rooms?.[roomId]?.[socket.id];
}
```

Comment: What line is the error for? Also, you shouldn't need the optional chaining within the `if`, as you have already checked that the properties exist.

Comment: error comes when I run this line: delete rooms?.[roomId]?.[socket.id];

Comment: Can you share the full error trace?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29721205/4722345)

Comment: A simpler reproduction of the issue would be useful as well. `delete null` and `delete undefined` work fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `?.` in the delete: `delete rooms[roomId][socket.id];`
It tells typescript that the value might be undefined (and you cannot do `delete undefined`, which is the error you get). You have already checked that that the value exists, so it's fine.